# How to automatically update the reference and cross-reference in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2019

I know we can highlight certain content, and right click on the "grey" caption and number to "update field", so that the reference/cross-reference within the highlighted area will be updated. However, this cannot be achieved when the entire document is selected for a long document with many figures and tables. So I am now updating it section by section.

So is there a quicker way to update the reference/cross-reference in one go, or can I ask why sometimes the "update field" is not available?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `CTRL+A` followed by `F9` for that purpose.

Comment: Great, it does!

Answer (score 0):

While pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and then <kbd>F9</kbd> may suffice for basic documents, this approach does not update the figure numbers inside text boxes. One common instance where this issue arises is when you add a caption to an image with a layout style other than "In Line with Text." In such cases, MS Word inserts the caption inside a text box.

### A More Effective Solution:

To reliably update numbering for figures, tables, and even cross-references, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to open the print preview. This action forces MS Word to update all numbers. To exit the print preview and return to your document, press <kbd>Esc</kbd>.